# Plot of two ordinal variables?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, ordinal-data, social-science, qualitative

It is common to represent various (ordinal, social) attributes on a pair of axes as in the examples below. In general, what is this sort of graph/representation called?

It is, perhaps, useful to think in these terms and we can recognise the resulting types/points. Examples of the such graphs are included below (Control vs Warmth in Child Development, belief vs knowledge in Religion, morals vs ethics in D'n'D or Ethics or social vs economics in Politics).

Perhaps Principal Component Analysis or Factor Analysis is relevant, but I am more concerned with using such representation to qualitatively discuss or compare various points of view rather than to analyse raw data.

[image: Parenting Styles]
[image: Belief vs Knowledge]
[image: Ethics vs Morals]
[image: Political Compass]